# Better way of decoding json values

Tags: go

Assume a JSON object with the general format

```
  "accounts": [
    {
      "id": "<ACCOUNT>", 
      "tags": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I can create a struct with corresponding json tags to decode it like so

```
 type AccountProperties struct {
    ID AccountID `json:"id"`
    MT4AccountID int `json:"mt4AccountID,omitempty"`
    Tags []string `json:"tags"`
  }

  type Accounts struct {
    Accounts []AccountProperties `json:"accounts"`
  }
```

But the last struct with just one element seems incorrect to me. Is there a way I could simply say `` type Accounts []AccountProperties `json:"accounts"` `` instead of creating an entire new struct just to decode this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need somewhere to store the json string `accounts`.  Using a:

```
var m map[string][]AccountProperties
```

suffices, though of course you then need to know to use the string literal `accounts` to access the (single) map entry thus created:

```
type AccountProperties struct {
    ID           string   `json:"id"`
    MT4AccountID int      `json:"mt4AccountID,omitempty"`
    Tags         []string `json:"tags"`
}

func main() {
    var m map[string][]AccountProperties
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
    fmt.Println(err, m["accounts"])
}
```

See complete [Go Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/4EnKGRjN7Gx) (I had to change the type of `ID` to `string` and fix the missing `{` in the json).

---

As [Dave C points out in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642677/better-way-of-decoding-json-values/57642737?noredirect=1#comment101742334_57642737), this is no shorter than just using an anonymous struct type:

```
var a struct{ Accounts []AccountProperties }
```

in terms of the `Unmarshall` call (and when done this way it's more convenient to *use*).  Should you want to use an anonymous struct like this in a `json.Marshall` call, you'll need to tag its single element to get a lowercase encoding: without a tag it will be called `"Accounts"` rather than `"accounts"`.

(I don't claim the map method to be *better*, just *an alternative*.)

Comment: thanks I believe this is better than making a struct with 1 element in side, although wouldn't it be nice if we could tag just a single variable pffft ty

Comment: Instead of a map (which has different undesirable unmarshalling behaviour) I'd just use a anonymous struct variable: https://play.golang.org/p/70ggPCSt3Qe

Comment: @DaveC: sure, though you'll want to annotate it with a `json:"accounts"` tag to get the right json encoding, where needed ... but either way, you're back to what the OP asked to avoid: a struct just to hold the slice of structs.

Comment: No tag required for unmarshalling. There is a difference between defining a package level struct type (what the OP wanted to avoid) and a one-line anonymous struct variable (which is just as short as your map version and has better unmarshalling behaviour; `json.Unmarshall` will treat the map different that does the struct type).